# How to reduce PSU noise?

Tags: power-supply, micro-atx, flex

I'm in a rather tight spot.

I'm building a custom PC that HAS to be a slim mATX supporting case. I found one on microcenter.com.

Here's the link: [Slim Case](http://microcenter.com/product/284178/DM-387_mATX_Slim_Computer_Case)

It comes with a 275 Watt power supply, which is stock, that I'm going to replace. I found one that has good reviews except for the fact that some say it is loud. Here's the link: [PSU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817338081).

Now this begs a few questions. I've read a few articles that say this PSU will support mATX boards; Newegg says mini ITX boards. I'm not too familiar with ITX boards, but they clearly have to support the same processors. My assumption is that it will work as long as it has the correct connections. Am I correct in that reasoning?

Also is the issue of noise. The computer will not eat the 400 watts that the PSU has been shown to provide. Although it is a slim case, it will be well ventilated. My hope is that being that the PSU will probably only be used at 50% of its max, the noise will be at minimal. Does load typically have an impact on the "noise" a PSU produces?

I should also note that the PSU is a flex ATX.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The reviews for that PSU seem to indicate a *lot* of them failing

Answer (score 1):

mini-ATX and mini-ITX are interchangeable as far as mounting and connections. The difference is that ITX only supports low power VIA chipsets that only need passive cooling.

A switched-mode PSU will definitely make less noise in a low power situation. Usually, the fan is the source of most noise. You may discern a slight hum, and that depends on the quality of the PSU. If you pay enough money you should get a near-silent PSU. Other factors may make the PSU in question rather noisy, and they are related to design and manufacture.

FlexATX is an Intel specced design that is usually smaller (to fit smaller cases) than a standard-sized PSU. It is compatible with ATX, mini-ATX, and mini-ITX motherboards.

Comment: actually no, there's Intel core i3 and atom mini ITX boxen as well as AMD ones, many of which arn't passively cooled